# Regular expression not working in python

Tags: python, regex

Why doesn't this work in Python

```
x=re.match('/^([a-z]){3}$/','ssw')
```

I am trying to check strings with length 3 and only small letters. Am I missing anything? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use delimiters in python...

```
x=re.match('^([a-z]){3}$','ssw')
```

Also, it is always a good habit to raw your regex strings:

```
x=re.match(r'^([a-z]){3}$','ssw')
```

The capture group does not quite make sense. If you want to only test a match, remove them:

```
x=re.match(r'^[a-z]{3}$','ssw')
```

If you want to capture all three letters, put the quantifier inside:

```
x=re.match(r'^([a-z]{3})$','ssw')
```

Because as it is right now, if there is a match, the capture group will only contain the last letter.

Comment: What does 'rawing' your regex strings do?

Comment: @xander It prevents some substitutions. E.g. `r'\ba\b'` will correctly match the letter-word `a`. But `'\ba\b'` will fail because `\b` is first interpreted I think as the 'backslash' character.

Answer (score 0):

put `{3}` inside capturing groups and remove the forward slashes,

```
^([a-z]{3})$
```

Your code would be,

```
x=re.match(r'^([a-z]{3})$','ssw')
>>> x
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f13bfdf98a0>
>>> x.group()
'ssw'
```

It captures the input only if the input contains 3 lowercase alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

The characters '^' and '$' are meta character in python, so:

```
x=re.match('^([a-z]){3}$','ssw')
x.group(0)
```

If you wand to match the '^' and '$' characters, you need to escape them:

```
x=re.match('/\^([a-z]){3}\$/', '/^ssw$/')
x.group(0)
```